Deploying CRM Analytics App & it's associated Template metadata make Source App N/A in Template
I'm trying to set up a CI/CD pipeline with multiple orgs for developing an CRM Analytics App & Template.
So my flow is to build an App & some Dashboards in Dev 1 org, and then using the App create a Template.
Once I've the Template, I'm retrieving the App (WaveApplication) and the Template (WaveTemplateBundle) metadata via VS Code.
Now, when I deploy both App and Template to a UAT environment then the App does show that there is an associated Template with it, but the Template deployed in UAT environment shows Source App column as N/A, as it is decoupled. Is there a way we can recouple them again in UAT environment? Or does that means, that the App and Template remains coupled in Dev 1 environment only? (but then how can another Developer work from, say, a Dev 2 environment along side Dev 1, since without coupling of App & template, we can't Update a Template in Dev 2 environment?
